# ERROR TypeError: this.user.setPassword is not a function in angular 5 ?

Tags: angular, angular5, frontend

Working with a simple angular5 app in front end , i want to do the edit of profil 
when the users wants to, so i have a button setting related to component ParametresComponent .

What i do first is show the user information with function get UserInfo() , after that when the user finish modifiying his account , he can save the changes , (he can change only 'Tel' and 'password') .

So i have a class Model User.ts :

```
export class  User{

  id:number;
  username:string;
  password:string;
  prenom:string;
  nom:string;
  tel:string;
  cin:string ;

  setId(value: number) {
    this.id = value;
  }

  setUsername(value: string) {
    this.username = value;
  }

  setPassword(value: string) {
    this.password = value;
  }

  setPrenom(value: string) {
    this.prenom = value;
  }

  setNom(value: string) {
    this.nom = value;
  }

  setTel(value: string) {
    this.tel = value;
  }

  setCin(value: string) {
    this.cin = value;
  }



}
```

The parametreComponent.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import * as _swal from 'sweetalert';
    import { SweetAlert } from 'sweetalert/typings/core';
    import {AbstractControl, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
    import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';
    import {User} from '../Admin/Models/User';
    import {Devloppeur} from '../Admin/Models/Devloppeur';
    import {DevloppeurService} from '../../../service/devloppeur.service';
    import {ClientService} from '../../../service/client.service';
    import {AuthenticationService} from '../../../service/authentication.service';
    const swal: SweetAlert = _swal as any;

    function passwordMatch(control: AbstractControl):{[key: string]: boolean}{

      const password = control.get('password');
      const Confirmationpassword = control.get('Confirmationpassword');

      if( !password || !Confirmationpassword) {
        return null; }

      if(password.value === Confirmationpassword.value){
        return null;
      }

      return {
        mismatch:true
      }

    }

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-parametres',
      templateUrl: './parametres.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./parametres.component.scss']
    })
    export class ParametresComponent implements OnInit {

      form: FormGroup;
      user:User  = new User();
      id:number;
      constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
                  public router:Router,
                  private authService:AuthenticationService,
                  public activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute,
                  private devService:DevloppeurService,
                  private clientServ:ClientService) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.id = this.authService.getAuthenticatedUserId();
        this.getUserInfo();

        this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
          prenom: [''] ,
          nom: [''],
          tel: ['', Validators.required],
          cin: [''],
          username : [''],
          passwordG: this.formBuilder.group({
            password: ['',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(9)]],
            Confirmationpassword : ['',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(9)]]

          }, {validator: passwordMatch})

        });
      }

      getUserInfo(){
        this.clientServ.getUser(this.id)
          .subscribe((data:any)=>{
            this.user = data;
          },err=>{
            console.log('there is an error lady ! ');
          })

      }


      SaveEditUser(){
        this.user.setPassword(this.form.value.passwordG.password);
        this.user.setTel(this.form.value.tel);


        this.devService.saveUser(this.user)
          .subscribe((data:User)=>{
            swal("operation réussi !", "Great edited with success !", "success");
            this.router.navigate([ '/profil' ], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute });
          },err=>{
            console.log(err);
          })
      }


    }
```

And the parametres.Component.html :

```
<div >
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <strong>Modifier mon profil</strong>
      </div>

      <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="SaveEditUser()">

        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="company">Prenom</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="company" disabled [(ngModel)]="user.prenom"  formControlName="prenom"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="vat">Nom</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vat"  disabled [(ngModel)]="user.nom"   formControlName="nom" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="vat">Tel</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="vat"  [(ngModel)]="user.tel"  formControlName="tel" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="vat">Cin</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vat"   disabled [(ngModel)]="user.cin"  formControlName="cin" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="vat">Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vat"   disabled [(ngModel)]="user.username"  formControlName="username" />
            <div class="error" *ngIf="form.controls['username'].invalid && form.controls['username'].errors.required && (form.controls['username'].dirty || form.controls['username'].touched)">Please enter an email</div>
            <div class="error" *ngIf="form.controls['username'].invalid && form.controls['username'].errors.email && (form.controls['username'].dirty || form.controls['username'].touched)">Please enter a valid email</div>
            <div class="error" *ngIf="form.controls['username'].invalid && form.controls['username'].errors.emailTaken">This email has been taken, please use another one.</div>
          </div>


          <div formGroupName = "passwordG">

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="vat">Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="vat"    formControlName="password" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="vat">Confirmation Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="vat" formControlName="Confirmationpassword" />
            </div>


            <div *ngIf="(form.controls['passwordG'].invalid && form.controls['passwordG'].touched)" class="col-sm-3 text-danger">

              <ng-container *ngIf="form.controls['passwordG'].errors?.mismatch;
                then first else second"> </ng-container>

              <ng-template #first>
                Password do not match </ng-template>

              <ng-template #second>
                Password needs to be more than 8 characters
              </ng-template>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" [disabled] = "!form.valid"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i>Enregistrer Les modifications</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div><!--/.col-->
</div>
```

The problem is when saving i get this error :

```
ParametresComponent.html:8 ERROR TypeError: this.user.setPassword is not a function
    at ParametresComponent.SaveEditUser (parametres.component.ts:79)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ParametresComponent.html:8)
    at handleEvent (core.js:13530)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15039)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:14626)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:9945)
    at eval (core.js:12284)
    at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js)
```

i'm not able to understand why i'm getting this error ? any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the access specifier as public for all your methods,

```
public setPassword(value: string) {
    this.password = value;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but i'm always getting the same problem

Comment: you need to have a constructor in your class https://github.com/bhavsarjai/biddingApp/blob/e8fe4ef85fc4629cb750fa04b7e1cdeac8ad6527/app/User.ts

Comment: https://github.com/bhavsarjai/biddingApp/blob/e8fe4ef85fc4629cb750fa04b7e1cdeac8ad6527/app/user.service.ts

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions:
1) Try to add a constructor in User. 
2) In getUserInfo() try to save the object as a User type

```
getUserInfo(){
        this.clientServ.getUser(this.id)
          .subscribe((data:any)=>{
            this.user = data; // <-- this.user = data as User;
          },err=>{
            console.log('there is an error lady ! ');
          })
      }
```

Comment: u can keep it as any, the important is to add the : this.user = data as User; its like manually declaring that we are treat this object like User. let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning an object that you have gotten from your API to your `this.user` object. This means that your new user object is no longer of the type `User` as you can't pass methods on an object your receive from an API. If you wish to assign the object from the API to your `this.user`, you have to keep the original `this.user` which has called `new User` (thus creating the methods on the object's prototype). To do this, you should assign the properties of the API object rather than the object itself:

```
getUserInfo(){
  this.clientServ.getUser(this.id)
    .subscribe((data:any)=>{
      Object.assign(this.user, data);
    },err=>{
      console.log('there is an error lady ! ');
    });
}
```